# creating a new table with some NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, null

I have these tables

```
 id | tests    | results  
001 | testId_1 | 1  
001 | testId_2 | 1  
002 | testId_1 | 1  
003 | testId_2 | 1  
004 | testId_1 | 1  
004 | testId_2 | 1
```

and

```
test_id | tests  
   1234 | testId_1  
   4565 | testId_2
```

Is there a way to combine them to create a new table with `NULL` value for those `id`s that are missing a `testId_x` like so

```
 id | tests    | results  
001 | testId_1 | 1  
001 | testId_2 | 1  
002 | testId_1 | 1  
002 | testId_2 | NULL    
003 | testId_1 | NULL  
003 | testId_2 | 1  
004 | testId_1 | 1  
004 | testId_2 | 1
```

Comment: `with NULL value for those ids that are missing` .. but then you show NULL values for `results`, not `id`. You mention `testId_x`, but that doesn't match the rest of your question. Please clarify. *Always* declare the version of Postgres in use. Also, there is nothing in the question describing how to fill in values. The second table seems redundant in the example.

Comment: yes.  I want to show NULL values for `results` column, not `tests` column. The `testId_x` are the values for the `tests` column.  I'm askinig is there a way to combine the two tables above to get the last table, with the values assigned to NULL.  `v.9.3.5`

Comment: There are many ways. You need to describe the task more clearly or we can only guess. **[Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32729355/edit)** your question to clarify.

Comment: `Is there a way to combine them to create a new table with NULL value for those ids that are missing a testId_x  ...`  how is this not clear?  Is there a way to combine the two tables to produce another table where the missing values are NULL?

Comment: Are there only every two distinct values for `tests`? How is `testId_1` assigned to id `003`? The first missing row in a Cartesian product? Then why do we need your second table *at all*? You could just say: "Fill the first *n* gaps for `testId_1`. Why are there leading zeroes in your `id` column? You should provide a table definition (what you get with `\d tbl` in psql) so we can see data types and constraints. This is my last comment. Please edit your question to make it a proper question or it may get closed.